# Github pages shows blank page

Tags: html, reactjs, github, github-pages

My repo: https://github.com/something/personal_website
My website: https://website.com/

I can not figure out why my GitHub pages can’t load any of my source files. The files I want to load are in the src folder. Everything works as it should on localhost. It only loads index.html which is a white blank screen, I don't have anything coded in this file. I’ve seen a few similar posts about this issue but have not found any common discrepancies.

I have installed through npm the gh-pages module and done “npm run deploy”; this created my gh-pages branch. I’ve updated my package.json with the appropriate information. As far as I can tell I have no capital letters in my repository.

I hosted another website previously on Github Pages at this domain with no issues. It appears that Github pages and the process has changed since then and I can’t get it to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that your homepage is trying to load assets from https://something.com/personal_website/static/js/main.3edbf089.chunk.js rather than https://something.com/static/js/main.3edbf089.chunk.js.

Remove the `personal_website` extension from `homepage` in `package.json` and the routes should work properly.

Therefore your new `package.json` should look like:

```
{
  "homepage" : "https://something.github.io/",
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  ...
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, you have no idea how much this had been bothering me.

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: worked for me! now, the question is why are so many tutorials (including GitHub's) wrong then?

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure that your package.json contains

   `"homepage": "https://username.github.io/appname"`
2. If you are using BrowserRouter, set the basename:

   `<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>`
3. Your .env file **cannot** contain something like `PUBLIC_URL=/` when you do a deploy (it was the problem in my case)

Answer (score 2):

Adding   "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app", to your Package.JSON might solve your problem.

remember replace your github user name and your app name.

Answer (score 2):

I've been stuck to this for two days. And finally, I solved it.

It is working to local but after deployment it is opening the blank page.

Problem is we changed the homepage path. So We need to update paths which are in our code.

If I give an example with my case, I added homepage into the "package.json" file something like:

```
"homepage": "https://[YourGitHubAccountName].github.io/[YourProjectName]"
```

So after adding this, app doesn't work because The paths which are inside of my code need to be change.

For example:

**'/'** paths should become **'/[YourProjectName]'** or

**'/test'** should become **'/[YourProjectName]/test'**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32287671)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Answers, solves the problem for create-react-app.
when using vite, you have to set the correct **base** in **vite.config.js** as below.
Also note in vite, you don't need the "homepage" key in "package.json" file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/<REPO_NAME>/",
})
```

for more info, please refrence [gh-pages configuration for vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages)