# GitHub pages not finding images and JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, github-pages

Working from [this template](https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_nft_minting_dapp) to build a react website with smart contract interactions, I was able to get everything running and appearing smoothly on `localhost`. All site features worked and images rendered properly, but after building and deploying via `npm`, the gh-pages site does not appear to have found my image and JS components.

I've tried editing the `homepage` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451867/github-pages-shows-blank-page), to no avail. I've also gone through the `index.html` file and tried messing with the `scr` locations. I'm not sure what's going wrong, and I'm very new to all of this, so any help is appreciated!

[GH Repo](https://github.com/Jack-Baumgartel/Modern-Abstractions)

[GH Site](https://jack-baumgartel.github.io/Modern-Abstractions/)

Edit: Based on comments here, I've updated the relative paths for all images. This fixed the image display issue for some but not all images. `CONFIG` items are still broken in deploy, even though they work fine on `localhost`

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

I have looked into your repo, and the below line is your problem (occurs when your React deployed app is not in the root directory of your domain, but inside a sub folder):

```js
<StyledImg alt={"example"} src={"/config/images/example.gif"} />
```

When you use `/` you are not in your project root folder but at `myusername.github.io`, while you want `myusername.github.io/my-repo`.

## Solution

You can avoid this issue by replacing the above line with this one:

```js
<StyledImg alt={"example"} src=`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/config/images/example.gif"}` />
```

And put in your `package.json` the GitHub Page url, like so:

```js
"homepage": "https://jack-baumgartel.github.io/Modern-Abstractions"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to dig a little deeper into the `config/config.json`, and change the `src` variable from `Modern-Abstractions/config/config.json` to just `config/config.json`. Also adding the `"homepage"` to package.json helped! Thanks all!