# Why does my GitHub pages page show as a blank screen? (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, github

I recently set up the below project in GitHub. I created a GitHub page also shown below, but when I try to open the page it shows a blank screen.

https://github.com/Bcruise/ECommerceSite

https://bcruise.github.io/ECommerceSite/

I used exactly the same technique to create another GitHub page previously and it worked. But for some reason this one doesn’t and shows just the blank page.

I used the technique in the page below and my package.json and index.html are below also.

Does any have any idea what the problem might be?

https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@1,400;1,500&family=Poppins:wght@100;300&family=Urbanist:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,600;1,500;1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>





{
  "homepage": "https://Bcruise.github.io/ECommerceSite",
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to close your head element for a start

Comment: It is closed? What other issues are there?

Comment: Did you make sure you followed the [upgrade guide for v18](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html)? You say you used the same technique previously but that may have been an older version. A lot has changed.

Comment: Works fine, what did you changed?

Comment: Take a look this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73044626/19583111 I hope it is helpful.