# Trouble With GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've seen a few of these posts on StackOverflow already, though I really can't seem to get mine working no matter what I try.

I am trying to host a webpage, though when deploying I am left with a blank screen, and the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in main.e7fa3b75.js:1
```

I've seen [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) which suggest it is a problem with the pathing to my static files, though I cant seem to sort it out.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451867/github-pages-shows-blank-page) post suggests I should remove an extension from my `package.json`, though I don't use that extension.

[This](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23595) post says I should remove the repository name from the `homepage` field in the `package.json`, though that also wouldn't work for me.

I'm out of ideas, [here](https://github.com/jcdw99/jcdw99.github.io) is the repo, if someone doesn't mind taking a look?

I have got it to render the website for a few moments, only to disappear to the same white screen moments later. There are no problems if I run the page on local host.

**UPDATE**

I have since got the application to host, but only if I explicitly visit the URL of the landing page.
`https://jcdw99.github.io/`

From the landing page there is a `/papers` route which can be reached from the navbar. If you press on the button, the page renders. Though, if you try to explicitly view the page, by manually visiting
`https://jcdw99.github.io/papers` it returns a 404.

Any help?

Comment: Do you see the same behavior locally as well? like visiting `http://localhost:3000/papers`.   
Also I don't see `/pages` route there is only `/papers` in the routes which point to `<Pages />`

Comment: my bad- I meant papers, pages is what I used to call the route. What I've noticed is: If I navigate to the home page using the link indicated in package.json, the webpage opens (try it yourself). If I use the navbar, everything navigates correctly. However, if I try to navigate to one of the routes without the navbar, IE by entering the url explicitly, I get a 404..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<HashRouter>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>` since Github pages don't support HTML5 history API (see [notes on client side routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing)) but [React BrowserRouter uses it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974369/what-is-the-difference-between-hashrouter-and-browserrouter-in-react#:%7E:text=Simply%2C%20BrowserRouter%20syncs%20the%20UI,of%20your%20URL%20to%20sync.). See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74149347/7801965) with similar problem.

One observation is if you navigate directly using `#` in the url, like https://jcdw99.github.io/#/papers it works!

Comment: Thank you for the help!
I've changed it to a ```<HashRouter>``` and it doesn't seem to function differently. I tried navigating to [https://jcdw99.github.io/#/papers](https://jcdw99.github.io/#/papers) though it navigates to the home page, rather than the ```/papers``` router? Do you observe the same results?

Comment: On second attempt, I followed the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984401/react-router-not-working-with-github-pages/74149347#74149347) that you've linked, and changed my ```homepage:``` field in ```package.json``` to also include the ```#```. This seems to have fixed the issue.